# A question about an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

Suppose that $\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle. Let $D$ be a point inside the triangle so that $\overline{DA}=13$, $\overline{DB}=12$, and $\overline{DC}=5$. Find the length of $\overline{AB}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? You are much more likely to receive helpful comments (at least from me) if you show that you've worked on it some by yourself.

Comment: Let $\overline{AB}=x$. I got an equation:

Comment: Measure angle D = 90

Comment: $\frac{1}{4}\left[\sqrt{(625-x^{2})(x^{2}-1)}+\sqrt{(324-x^{2})(x^{2}-64)}+\sqrt{(289-x^{2})(x^{2}-49)}\right]=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x^{2}$. But it is not easy to solve it.

Comment: Oh i m sorry i m wrong

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let s be the side of the equilateral triangle

Using cosine formula for the triangle

$$\frac{13^2 + 5^2 - s^2}{2.5.13} = \cos\alpha\tag1$$
$$\frac{12^2 + 5^2 - s^2}{2.5.12} = \cos\beta\tag2$$
$$\frac{12^2 + 13^2 - s^2}{2.13.12} = \cos\gamma\tag3$$

Now we have $\gamma + \alpha + \beta = \pi$
$$\cos\gamma = \cos(\pi - \alpha - \beta)$$
Knowing $\cos(\pi - \theta) = \cos(\theta)$

$$\Rightarrow \cos\gamma = \cos(\alpha + \beta)$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos\gamma = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$\Rightarrow (\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha\cos\beta)^2 = \sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta$$
$$\Rightarrow (\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha\cos\beta)^2 = (1 - \cos^2\alpha)(1 - \cos^2\beta)$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos^2\alpha + \cos^2\beta + \cos^2\gamma - 2.\cos\alpha.\cos\beta.\cos\gamma -1 = 0\tag4$$

Applying $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ to $(4)$ and simplifying we have

$$s^4 - 338.s^2 + 17761 = 0$$

using Heron's formula we have

$$\Rightarrow s^2  = \pm 60 . \sqrt3 + 169$$
$$\Rightarrow s = \pm\sqrt{\pm 60 . \sqrt3 + 169}$$

as Area of a triangle is real and positive

$$s = \sqrt{60 . \sqrt3 + 169}$$

Comment: Nice diagrams. What software are you using to produce them?

Comment: @antirealist: I used the [geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/webstart/geogebra.html) online applet

Comment: Actually the side (not the "area") is real and positive with $s=\sqrt{-60\sqrt{3}+169}$ too.  You gave the root where the concurrency point is inside the triangle, but there is also one, mine, where the concurrency point is outside the triangle.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider an equilateral  triangle ABC and a Point P such that $\overline{AP} = 12$, $\overline{BP} = 13$ and $\overline{CP} = 5$.

Let $P'$, $P'_1$ and $P'_2$ be the reflection of the Point $P$ along  $\overline{BC}$, $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{AB}$

Then we have

$${\triangle APB} \cong {\triangle AP'_2B}$$
$${\triangle APC} \cong {\triangle AP'_1B}$$
$${\triangle BPC} \cong {\triangle BP'C}$$

Thus we can safely say,
The area of the hexagon $AP'_1CP'BP'_2 = 2. {\triangle ABC}$

${\triangle AP'_2B}$, ${\triangle AP'_1B}$ and ${\triangle BP'C}$ are isosceles with an apex angle of $120^o$ and composed of $30^o$ and $60^o$ right angle triangle

Thus we have

$$\overline {P'_1P'_2} = 12\sqrt3$$
$$\overline {P'P'_2} = 13\sqrt3$$
$$\overline {P'_1P'} = 5\sqrt3$$

which implies $\angle P'P'_1P'_2 = 90^o$

So the area of the hexagon $AP'_1CP'BP'_2$

$$= \triangle AP'_1P'_2 + \triangle P'P'_1C + \triangle P'P'_2B + \triangle P'P'_1P'_2$$
$$= 12^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 5^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 13^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}(5\sqrt3)(12\sqrt3)$$
$$=169\frac{\sqrt3}{2} + 90$$
$${\triangle ABC} =169\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 45$$

Now, given the sides of the triangle $\overline {AB}$ = $\overline {BC}$ = $\overline {CA}$ = $a$, then

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2 = {\triangle ABC} =169\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 45$$

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2 =  169\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 45$$
$$a^2 =  169 + 45\frac{4}{\sqrt3}$$
$$a = \sqrt{169 + 45\frac{4}{\sqrt3}}$$

Simplifying

$$a = \sqrt{169 + 60\sqrt3}$$

Comment: I cannot follow this b/c the 120°-30°-30° triangles seem to be misidentified.  Please check. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider an equilateral  triangle ABC and a Point P such that $\overline{AP} = 12$, $\overline{BP} = 13$ and $\overline{CP} = 5$.

Rotate $P$ clockwise along $A$ by $60^o$ to $B'$, along $B$ by $60^o$ to $C'$, along $C$ by $60^o$ to $A'$

We note that, 
$${\triangle APB} \cong ${\triangle ACB'}$$
$${\triangle APC} \cong ${\triangle A'CB}$$
$${\triangle BPC} \cong ${\triangle AC'B}$$

Thus we have, the area of the hexagon $AB'CA'BC'$
$$=2.{\triangle ABC}$$

We also observe that
${\triangle APB'}$, ${\triangle BPC'}$ and ${\triangle A'PC}$ are equilateral triangles

${\triangle PCB'} \cong {\triangle AC'P} \cong {\triangle A'BP} = RightAngle {\triangle}$

Thus we can say

$$2.{\triangle ABC} = [AB'CA'BC']$$
$$= {\triangle APB'} + {\triangle BPC'} + {\triangle A'PC} + 3.{\triangle PCB'}$$
$$= 12^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 13^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 5^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{4}  + 3.\frac{1}{2}(5)(12)$$
$$=169\frac{\sqrt3}{2} + 90$$
$${\triangle ABC} =169\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 45$$

Now, given the sides of the triangle $\overline {AB}$ = $\overline {BC}$ = $\overline {CA}$ = $a$, then

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2 = {\triangle ABC} =169\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 45$$

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{4}a^2 =  169\frac{\sqrt3}{4} + 45$$
$$a^2 =  169 + 45\frac{4}{\sqrt3}$$
$$a = \sqrt{169 + 45\frac{4}{\sqrt3}}$$

Simplifying

$$a = \sqrt{169 + 60\sqrt3}$$

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia [article on equilateral triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle#Other_properties) quotes the following theorem from "Curious Properties of the Circumcircle and Incircle of an Equilateral Triangle," by Prithwijit De (http://ms.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Abstracts%2041/41-1-7.pdf):

**Theorem:** Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with side $s$, and let $P$ be a point in the plane of the triangle with distances $p$, $q$, and $r$ to $A$, $B$, and $C$, respectively. Then $$3(p^4+q^4+r^4+s^4) = (p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2)^2{\textrm.}$$
Solving $3(5^4+12^4+13^4+s^4) = (5^2+12^2+13^2+s^2)^2$ for $s$ gives $s=\sqrt{169\pm 60\sqrt3}$. Because $P$ is inside the triangle, $s>13$, which allows only $s=\sqrt{169+ 60\sqrt3}$, the same solution others have obtained.

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to use Coordinate Geometry,

[image]

WLOG we can assume the coordinates of $A,B,C$ to be $(x,y),(-a,0),(a,0)$ respectively and $D$ to be $(h,k).$

As $\triangle  ABC$ is equilateral $(x-a)^2+(y-0)^2=(x+a)^2+(y-0)^2=(-a-a)^2+(0-0)^2$

From the first relation we find $4ax=0\implies x=0$ as $a\ne0$

From the second relation we find $y^2=3a^2\implies y=\sqrt3a$ assuming  $a>0$

So, $\overline{AB}=2a$

So, $\overline{AD}^2=(h-0)^2+(k-\sqrt3a)^2$ But $\overline{AD}=13$
$\implies (h-0)^2+(k-\sqrt3a)^2=13^2--->(1)$

Similarly, for $BD,CD$ respectively,

$(h+a)^2+k^2=12^2--->(2)$ and  $(h-a)^2+k^2=5^2--->(3)$

So here we have three equations with three unknowns $a,h,k$

One way to solve this could be  as follows :

From $(2)-(3),4ah=119\implies h=\frac{119}{4a}$

From $(2)-(1),2ah+2\sqrt3ak=2a^2-25\implies k=\frac{4a^2-169}{4\sqrt3a} $ (putting $ah=\frac{119}4$)

Putting the values of $h,k$ in terms of $a$ in $(1),$

$$\left(\frac{119}{4a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{4a^2-169}{4\sqrt3a}-\sqrt3a\right)^2=13^2$$

$$\implies 64a^4-32\cdot169a^2+169^2+3(119^2)=0$$

which is a Quadratic Equation in $a^2$

Comment: Could somebody please verify this?

Comment: Your quadratic equation has four roots $\pm\frac{\sqrt{169\pm60*\sqrt3}}{2}$

Comment: +1. Which at least is in coherence with my result. Considering the Point is inside the triangle, the only solution viable is $\frac{\sqrt{169+60*\sqrt3}}{2}*2 = \sqrt{169+60*\sqrt3}$

Comment: @Abhijit, thanks for your feedback. Just to reiterate I have assumed $a>0$, so negative roots can be ignored.

Comment: In your derivation, the first four line is implied for a equilateral triangle and can be ignored I believe.

Comment: @Abhijit, I have just included them for better clarity.